# Detecting prohibited words within a string

Tags: php, strpos

I have a function for checking bad words but it doesn't work how I want it to. For example test was a cuss word then if i said "testing" the function would count it as a cuss word. How would  i fix this so that it doesn't do that.

here is my code:

```
    function censor($message) {
        $badwords = $this->censor; //array with the cuss words.
        $message = @ereg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]','',strtolower(' '.$message.' '));
        foreach($badwords as $bad) {
            $bad = trim($bad);
            if(strpos($message.' ', $bad.' ')!==false) {
                if(strlen($bad)>=2) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use \b in the regex (at the start and end). It matches word boundaries.

Comment: `ereg_` functions are deprecated for a reason. Suppressing a notice with `@` does not make it a bit better. Switch to `preg_` functions.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher Where do i add that?

Answer (score 2):

First, [`ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0.

Now, to your question: you can use `\b` as a word boundary.

> Simply put: `\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using
>   a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`.

See [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more details.

---

You could even use something like the code below which i copied from Example 2 of PHP's [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) documentation:

```
$string = 'The quickest brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/ quick /';
$patterns[1] = '/ brown /';
$patterns[2] = '/ fox /';

echo preg_replace($patterns, ' *** ', $string);

Output: The quickest *** *** jumped over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what line do i add that?